# jQuery Sortable elements not always staying inside parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a sortable interface with two lists using jQuery-UI.

I have the following code working for the most part, with the exception that sometimes the dragged element will fly to the right of the list. See [SSCE here](https://jsfiddle.net/2qLw0vo2/1/). Try dragging 'Rates' down one position and then back up to observe the problem.

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#enabledCategories, #disabledCategories").sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    connectWith: ".categorySortable",
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".sortHandle",
    revert: 50
  }).disableSelection();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("<style>")
    .prop("type", "text/css")
    .html(".sortable-placeholder { height: " + ($(".list-group-item").outerHeight(true) + 8) + "px; }")
    .appendTo("head");
});
```

```
.panel-manage .list-group-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 14px;
}
.panel-manage .list-group-item i {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.panel-manage .list-group-item .panel-item-text {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0px;
}
.panel-manage .list-group-buttons {
    float: right;
}
.panel-manage .list-group-item button {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    float: left;
}
.panel-manage .list-group-item button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```
<div class="panel panel-primary panel-manage" id="panel-categories">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Tabs</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="list-group categorySortable ui-sortable" id="enabledCategories">
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> Home                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> Rates                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> FAQ                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> About Us                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Disabled:</h4>
    <div class="list-group categorySortable ui-sortable" id="disabledCategories">
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> Calendar                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> Blog                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <span class="panel-item-text">
                        <i class="sortHandle fa fa-sort ui-sortable-handle"></i> Info                      </span>
        <div class="list-group-buttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-warning category-edit" data-book-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-danger category-delete" data-book-id="" data-book-name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success category-add" value="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For next time, consider using the `<>` button to put your live demo right here on the site, rather than off on jsFiddle and duplicated as code blocks here.

Comment: BTW: Pretty! (The colors and stuff.)

Comment: Thanks! It's actually all just Start Bootstrap defaults, applied correctly they look great.

Comment: *That's* why it looked familiar. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `.list-group-item` element is being dragged, it is absolutely positioned. To resolve the issue that you are seeing, you could relatively position the parent `.list-group` element, and then add `left: 0` to the draggable `.list-group-item` element.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/uudzue2o/)

```
.list-group {
  position: relative;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Would it be possible to make the whole div draggable for sorting, not just the icon?

Answer (score 0):

The element had no left set so it was going to the right.
[**The working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinayakjadhav/2qLw0vo2/3/)

```
.panel-body{
  padding:0;
}
.list-group-item{
  left: 15px;
}
```

Also Try the `containment` API given by jquery-ui.